# (laravel) The Excel-sheet is uploaded empty

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I don't know why my excel sheet is uploaded empty thats my controller function

```
public function uploadedCars(Request $request)
{

    if (!$request->hasFile('file'))
        return Response::json(['error' => 'No File Sent.']);

    if (!$request->file('file')->isValid())
        return Response::json(['error' => 'File is not valid']);

    $file = $request->file('file');
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();


    if ($extension == "csv" || $extension == "CSV" || $extension == "xlsx" || $extension == "XLSX"
        || $extension == "rtf" || $extension == "rtf" ||  $extension == "ods" ||  $extension =="ODS"){}
    else {
        $status = 'sorry this file extension is not allowed';
        return Redirect::back()->with(session()->flash('Error_flash_message', $status));
    }

    // $file = time().'.'.$request->file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $path = $file->move(public_path('uploads'), $file);

    $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
        })->get();


    if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $insert[] = [
                        'cat_id' => $value->cat_id, 'car_name' => $value->car_name
                        ,'starting_price' => $value->starting_price
                        ,'image' => $value->image , 'car_name_ar' => $value->car_name_ar
                        ,'year_start' => $value->year_start , 'year_end' => $value->year_end
                    ];
        }
        if(!empty($insert)){
            DB::table('cars')->insert($insert);

        }
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', true);
}
```

and That's My form

```
<form method="POST" action="uploadedCars" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

        Select Excel-Sheet to upload:
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
  <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit"> Upload Sheet </button>
</form>
```

can someone help me ? when I dd() the returned data from uploading it gives me nothing , and my excel sheet is not empty ?

Comment: Debug it line by line.

Comment: I've already done that , until dd(count($data)) 
it is 0

Comment: what does $path echo's??Do you get correct path in return?

Comment: @nikhil_gandhi yes   path: "foldersName/public/uploads"

Comment: What if you upload it manually (ftp, ssh) and execute the script with it? I suppose, that the file uploads correct, it is the reader, who do it wrong.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan already I'm working on ssh , the uploading  is correct but if I open the file from the (uploads) folder , It is empty nothing is recorded in it it isnot the reader who does it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
$path = $file->move(public_path('uploads'), $file);
```

with

```
$destinationPath = 'uploads';
$file->move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());
```

Comment: Thank you , I've solved it , I forgot to ctrl + s my excel .